# NSString stringByAppendingString memory issue

Tags: memory, nsstring

On objective-c with iPhone:

I want to make a append with strings, but can I use autorelease? Is this right?

```
NSString *str1 = [[NSString alloc] initWithString:@"STR1"];
NSString *str2 = [[NSString alloc] initWithString:@"STR2"];

NSString *s = [[str1 autorelease] stringByAppendingString:[str2 autorelease]];
```

will this remove the *str1 and *str2 memory?

And for example, if I have a method:

```
+(void) doSomething
{
    NSString *str1 = [[NSString alloc] initWithString:@"STR1"];
    NSString *str2 = [[NSString alloc] initWithString:@"STR2"];

    NSString *s = [[str1 autorelease] stringByAppendingString:[str2 autorelease]];
    [[NSClassFromString(s) alloc] init];
}
```

should I dealloc the *s pointer???

Answer (score 3):

The general rule is that if you call `alloc` you have to call `release` on that resource.

So for your first example, str1 and str2 **will** be removed from memory, however you're not following convention for your autoreleases. Instead add the autorelease to the allocation line:

```
NSString *str1 = [[[NSString alloc] initWithString:@"STR1"] autorelease];
NSString *str2 = [[[NSString alloc] initWithString:@"STR2"] autorelease];
```

For the second example, because you're not calling alloc for the `stringByAppendingString` method, you don't need to release `s`.

Read through the [iPhone Memory Management](http://developer.apple.com/iPhone/library/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/MemoryMgmt.html) guide.  It is worth the up front investment, so that you don't have to deal with these issues down the road.  After that, read through [Akosma Software's](http://akosma.com/2009/01/28/10-iphone-memory-management-tips/) blog post.

Comment: I'm sorry I mjme is str1 and str2 is userInterface,I edited the text